# steam error with vgui2_s.so - unsure how to repair

Tags: steam

Cannot open steam, it comes up with the following error:

Could not load module 'vgui2_s.so'.

For more information visit https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9205-OZVN-0660.

I then ran the following in the terminal, i'm not clear on what I need to do next:

walkersmiths@walkersmiths-V520S-08IKL:~$ cd ~/.steam/bin32

walkersmiths@walkersmiths-V520S-08IKL:~/.steam/bin32$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd vgui2_s.so

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f13000)
libtier0_s.so => ./libtier0_s.so (0xf7dd3000)
libvstdlib_s.so => ./libvstdlib_s.so (0xf7d65000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf7bfc000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xf7bef000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf7bda000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xf7b79000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf7b2e000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf7a71000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf757c000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf744b000)
libopenal.so.1 => not found
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0xf7445000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xf743c000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xf7420000)
libXtst.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6 (0xf7418000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7413000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf728d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf726e000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7264000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f15000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7162000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf6f86000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6f58000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf6f4c000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0xf6f29000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xf6eca000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf6e98000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0xf6e5e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf6e3f000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf6d7e000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf6d79000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xf6d6a000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf6d61000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xf6d3a000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xf6beb000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xf6bc0000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xf69d9000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xf69c1000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xf696e000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf690e000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf6897000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf688e000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf6871000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6853000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf684f000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf6848000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xf6835000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xf6829000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xf6825000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf6821000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xf6772000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xf676c000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xf675d000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xf6731000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf6719000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0xf66b6000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xf660d000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0xf6602000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xf65f9000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0xf65a1000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xf6570000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0xf6567000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact missed library is named

> ```
> libopenal.so.1 => not found
> ```

You have to install [it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libopenal.so.1) with

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386
```

Comment: thanks - I have now installed the missed library as suggested, but now we cannot open Steam. When we click the icon it is unresponsive. There is no associated error message with it this time.

Comment: on turning on the computer we can log in. but then the window disappears and there is nothing. how can in find out what is wrong?

Comment: I do not really know what is happened here.